# Dynamic font download in iOS need download com_apple_MobileAsset_Font.xml every launch?

Tags: ios, uikit, uifont

I want to use a dynamic font in my app. And I found in apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Listings/DownloadFont_ViewController_m.html) they download a xml every launch, even though I have downloaded the font before.

Why? What's the usage of this file？

Is there any bugs in this sample code, or I need to accept this if I want to use this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code is typically intended to the lead developer in the right direction, versus giving them a fully functioning and optimized solution.

You should save the font data after downloading it and then on startup you can retrieve it locally with some code like this.

```
+ (void)loadFontAtPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
    if (!data) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font. Data at path is null");
        return;
    }

    CFErrorRef error;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

    if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
    }

    CFRelease(font);
    CFRelease(provider);
}
```

From there you would call it as normal with `[UIFont fontWithName:size:]`.

Also requesting from a URL might be useful to you. [CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_FontManager_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL)